# GCC (MingW-w64) cannot find base constructor (!?)

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, constructor, mingw

I'm writing some hashmap implementations and have stumbled upon quite a peculiar problem.
So I have written an abstract class as follows:

```
// HashMap.hpp
template<typename K, typename V, typename HashFunc = std::hash<K>>
class HashMap
{
public:
    HashMap(unsigned int bucketLength = DEFAULT_BUCKET_LENGTH)
        : m_bucketsLength(bucketLength)
        , m_bucketsFilled(0)
    {
        m_keyValueVector.resize(m_bucketsLength, nullptr);
    }
    virtual ~HashMap()
    {

    }
...
};
```

And derived from it an implementation:

```
// DoubleHashMap.hpp
#include "HashMap.hpp"

template<typename K, typename V, typename HashFunc = std::hash<K>>
class DoubleHashMap : public HashMap<K, V>
{
public:
    DoubleHashMap(unsigned int bucketLength = DEFAULT_BUCKET_LENGTH)
        : HashMap(bucketLength) // This is the line at which the build fails
    {

    }
...
};
```

Everything works like a charm using Visual Studio 2013 but when trying to build it with MingW-w64 4.9.1 I get the following error:

> DoubleHashMap.h:11: error: class 'DoubleHashMap' does
>   not have any field named 'HashMap'
>            : HashMap(bucketLength)
>                ^

In other words it's as if the compiler cannot find the base constructor. 
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in MingW-w64?

EDIT: Tried different combinations of MingW compilers (MingW 4.8.3, TDM-GCC 4.8.1) and they all produce the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the name of the base class fully:

```
DoubleHashMap(unsigned int bucketLength = DEFAULT_BUCKET_LENGTH)
    : HashMap<K, V>(bucketLength)
{
  ...
```

Is it possible, by the way, that you meant to derive from `HashMap<K, V, HashFunc>` instead of just `HashMap<K, V>`?

Comment: That was it.  
Funny how MSVC compiled the code anyway.  

"Is it possible, by the way, that you meant to derive from HashMap<K, V, HashFunc> instead of just HashMap<K, V>?"

Yes, I just assumed I didn't need to since it had a default value. 

Alas it seems I tend to assume too much :)

Thanks!